# What is an equivalent of Swift's UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Basically, I am from a Swift SpriteKit background where `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` is a CGRect which represents the screen and can be manipulated in various ways like getting the middle of the screen by using

```
var screenCenter = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2)
```

I am working on a 2d puzzle game, hence I've set the camera to orthographic. I would like to manipulate the view in the game scene.
What is an equivalent of `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` in Unity (C# Scripting) that can manipulated to get various positions in a similar manner?

Comment: you need to explain whether you are doing a scene with perspective camera or ortho camera.  And you need to explain whether you mean on the Unity.UI layer (your Canvas and so on) or whether you mean in the actual game scene.  Folks are happy to help you but realise that in game engineering it's not like iOS .. there are incredibly different "types" of games. (You could be doing a shooter, a car race game, a gem puzzle, scrabble, or whatever.  Simply state what "type" of game you're doing.)

Comment: Thanks. I am working on a 2d puzzle game, hence I've set the camera to orthographic, also I am referring the actual game scene.

Comment: FYI you can click edit and put that info in the question.  for what you say, fafase has your answer, cheers.  be careful to develop games reactively, everything has to work and make sense and play the same on all screen ratios and sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be:

```
Screen.width;
Screen.height;
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html